# Passing $(this) to functions

Tags: jquery

In JQuery, how we can pass entire $(this) to a functions? Possible?

Comment: Yes, you can call a function in Javascript passing an object as a parameter. Why is this even a question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Um, it depends on what you are passing, but have you just tried the following:

```
function do_something_cool(jquery_link_object) {
  /* I do something awesome! */
}

$('a.my_link_class').click(function() {
  do_something_cool($(this));
});
```

This will pass the clicked link to the `do_something_cool` method.

Answer (score 0):

The `$(this)` element is exposed in most jQuery event operations. You can add a functional parameter to your jQuery handlers.

```
$("a.someClass").live("click", function(e) {
    // $(this) is a reference to the same <a> element.
    var link = $(this);
    doSomethingToLink(link);
});
```

Comment: Completely unrelated and on top of that, wrong: `e` is **not** a reference to the anchor, it is an **Event** Object.

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't very specific, but maybe you want something like this:

```
$("a.myLinkClass").click(
    function(){
        $(this).addClass('myClickedLinkClass'); // 'this' refers to the anchor element that was clicked
    }
);
```